# Failed to load resources with laravel 9, tailwindcss

Tags: php, laravel, tailwind-css

`i'm encountering an issue with my website where the css files, located in the resources folder, are failing to load. the message browser console displays an error message: Failed to load resources. i'm using laravel 9 for development and vite for tailwind css. i would appreciate your assistance in resolving this issue with me.

i added the ../ to my resource to see if it is a file path issue

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score -2):

To load CSS files in a Laravel application, you can follow these steps:

**1- Create or Organize Your CSS Files:**

You should have your CSS files ready. You can create a css folder in the **public** directory to store your CSS files, or you can use any directory structure that makes sense for your project.

**2-strong textLink the CSS Files in Your Blade View:**

Open the Blade view file where you want to include the CSS files (e.g., resources/views/welcome.blade.php or any other view file).
Use the asset() helper function to generate the URL to your CSS file. Here's an example:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('css/style.css') }}">
```

In this example, **style.css** is assumed to be in the **public/css** directory. The asset() function generates the correct URL for the asset based on your Laravel configuration.

Comment: i'm uisng vite, this method is not working vite, i'm using laravel 9 and tailwind css vite